# Scrape Wikipedia Using Python, Beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some challenges with a wiki table and hope someone who has done it before can give me advice. From the wikitable mw-collapsible table  I need to get the data into a pandas data frames. (The code does not work). I am not sure how to get this going. In this initial attempt to pull data it ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. Will appreciate your help!

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_South_Africa"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

# use the 'find_all' function to bring back all instances of the 'table' tag in the HTML and store in 'all_tables' variable
all_tables=soup.find_all("table")
all_tables

right_table=soup.find('table', class_='wikitable mw-collapsible')
right_table

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
H=[]
I=[]
J=[]
K=[]
L=[]
M=[]
N=[]
O=[]
P=[]
Q=[]
U=[]

for row in right_table.findAll('tr'):
    cells=row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==17:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
        G.append(cells[6].find(text=True))
        H.append(cells[7].find(text=True))
        I.append(cells[8].find(text=True))
        J.append(cells[9].find(text=True))
        K.append(cells[10].find(text=True))
        L.append(cells[11].find(text=True))
        M.append(cells[12].find(text=True))
        N.append(cells[13].find(text=True))
        P.append(cells[14].find(text=True))
        Q.append(cells[15].find(text=True))
        U.append(cells[16].find(text=True))

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['DATE'])
df['EC']=B
df['FS']=C
df['GAU']=D
df['KJN']=F
df['LIM']=G
df['MPU']=H
df['NW']=I
df['NC']=J
df['WC']=K
df['NEW']=L
df['TOTAL']=M
df['NEW']=N
df['TOTAL']=O
df['REC']=P
df['TESTED']=Q
df['REF']=U
df
```

Comment: what table are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aweful lot of work to get into a dataframe when pandas has the `read_html()` function to do precisely that (actually uses beautifulsoup under the hood).

`.read_html()` will return a list of dataframes (Ie the `<table>` tags in the html). It's just a matter of pulling out the one you want.

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_South_Africa"

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[3]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
          Date   EC   FS     GP   KZN   LP   MP   NW   NC    WC Confirmed        Deaths                                                         Rec                        Tested                           Ref
          Date   EC   FS     GP   KZN   LP   MP   NW   NC    WC       New  Total    New                         Total                           Rec                        Tested                           Ref
0   2020-03-04  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN    0.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           181                          [22]
1   2020-03-05  NaN  NaN    NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       1.0    1.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           [2]
2   2020-03-06  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       0.0    1.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN
3   2020-03-07  NaN  NaN    1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       1.0    2.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          [11]
4   2020-03-08  NaN  NaN    NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       1.0    3.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          [23]
5   2020-03-09  NaN  NaN    NaN   4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       4.0    7.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          [24]
6   2020-03-10  NaN  NaN    2.0   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       3.0   10.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           239                          [25]
7   2020-03-11  NaN  NaN    2.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0       3.0   13.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           645                      [12][26]
8   2020-03-12  NaN  0.0    1.0   1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN       3.0   16.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           848                  [27][28][29]
9   2020-03-13  NaN  NaN    4.0   2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   2.0       8.0   24.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           924                      [30][31]
10  2020-03-14  NaN  NaN    7.0   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   6.0      14.0   38.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          1017                      [32][33]
11  2020-03-15  NaN  NaN    7.0   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0      13.0   51.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          1476                   [34][3][35]
12  2020-03-16  NaN  NaN    7.0   NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN   2.0      11.0   62.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          2405                      [17][36]
13  2020-03-17  NaN  NaN   14.0   4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0      23.0   85.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          2911                      [18][37]
14  2020-03-18  NaN  NaN   16.0   3.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  10.0      31.0  116.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          3070                  [38][19][39]
15  2020-03-19  NaN  NaN   15.0   3.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  15.0      34.0  150.0    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                          4832                  [40][41][42]
16  2020-03-20  NaN  7.0   33.0   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0      52.0  202.0    NaN                           NaN                             2                          6438                      [43][44]
17         NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN                           NaN
18       Cases  0.0  7.0  109.0  24.0  1.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  56.0       NaN    NaN    NaN  including local transmission  including local transmission  including local transmission  including local transmission
```

Comment: @BhaveshBhana ya if it’s a <table> tag, try pandas first. Once I learned pandas pulled out tables in html, it was game changer for me. Although, parsing tables with beautifulsoup is a good way to learn how to use beautifulsoup and html.